# Solutions to the inequality $\frac{x(6+x)}{3+2x}\leq x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x(6+x)}{3+2x}\leq x$$
$$\frac{6x+x^2}{3+2x}-x\leq 0$$
$$(6x+x^2)(3+2x)-x(3+2x)^2\leq 0$$  $$x\neq\frac{-3}{2}$$

$$18x+12x^2+3x^2+2x^3-3x-2x^3=15x^2+15x\leq0$$
$$15x(x+1)\leq0$$
$$0\leq x \leq-1$$

Where I get it wrong? the answer is $x\geq3$ $-\frac{3}{2}\leq x\leq0$

Comment: From the 2nd line, if you're multiplying through by $3+2x$ your equation should result in $6x+x^2-x(3+2x)^2 \leq 0$

Comment: @MikeMiller I can not multiplying by $3+2x$ because I do not know if it is negative or not that why I multiple in $(3+2x)^2$

Comment: you still can't throw away $(3+2x)$ in going from the 3rd line to the 4th.

Comment: @abel why not? if it is the common denominator?

Comment: @gbox sorry, my first comment shouldn't be a square, but you can consider both cases afterwards.

Comment: @MikeMiller I tried it but did not the $-\frac{3}{2}$ sloution

Comment: i posted my explanation as an answer. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on the 3rd line: you expanded $-x(3+2x)^2=-3x-2x^3$ instead of $-9x-12x^2-4x^3$.
However, it's shorter to factor:
\begin{align}
p(x)&=(6x+x^2)(3+2x)-x(3+2x)^2 )\\
&= x(3+2x)(6+x-3-2x\\
&=x(3+2x)(3-x)
\end{align}
As $\lim_{x\to +\infty}p(x)=-\infty$, we deduce at once from the Intermediate Value Theorem that $p(x)\le 0$ for $x\ge 3$, then $p(x) \ge 0\,\,$  if $0\le x\le3$,  $\,p(x)\le 0\,\,$ again if $-\frac{3}{2}\le x \le 0\,\,$ and finally $p(x)\ge 0\,\,$ if $x\le -\frac{3}{2}$.

So the solutions are $-\frac{3}{2}\le x \le 0$ or $x\ge 3$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider two cases: $x\geq0$ and $x<0$. Think also, when multiplying by $3+2x$ preserves the inequality.

Comment: it is $-x^2+3x \leq 0$ and $-x^2+3x>0$?

Comment: @gbox Well, in your solution two cases should be considered before obtaining the third line. But earlier division by $x$ simplifies the solution.

Answer (score 1):

here i will write out the solution here.

$\begin{eqnarray}
{x(6+x) \over 3 + 2x} - x & \le & 0\\ 
{x(6+x) -x(3+2x) \over 3 + 2x} & \le & 0\\
{x^2 + 6x - 3x -2x^2 \over 3 + 2x} & \le & 0\\
{x(3-x) \over 3 + 2x}  & \le & 0
\end{eqnarray}$

the critical numbers of the rational function are $0, 3$ and $-3/2$ by sign analysis , you can conclude that $$ {x(3-x) \over 3 + 2x} \le 0 \ on \ -3/2 < x \le 0 \ and \ 3 \le  x < \infty $$

Comment: by sign analysis you mean to check when $x(3-x)>0$ and $3+2x<0$ or  $x(3-x)<0$ and $3+2x<0$?

Comment: @gbox, i meant the rational function may switch(in this case, it does) signs only across the critical numbers. so all need to do is pick a test point in each of the four segments separated by the critical numbers and decide the sign for the whole segment. e.g. if you evaluate the rational function at $x = 1,$ you find the value $LHS = 2/5$ which is positive, so $LHS > 0, 0 < x < 3$. do you get what i mean by sign analysis?